# PHP - intval() with min, max arguments

Tags: php, string, numbers

```
function intvalminmax($whatever, $min = 1, $max = 100){
  if(intval($whatever) < $min) return 1;
  elseif(intval($whatever) > $max) return $max;
  return intval($whatever);
}
```

is there any built-in PHP function that does something like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

no, but you could use `min(max(intval($whatever), $min), $max)` instead.

Comment: tx, that's exactly what I needed! because I hate it when I have to write my own function for every small thing :)

Answer (score 3):

You could combine `min` and `max`:

```
max($min, min(intval($val), $max))
```

Answer (score 2):

Answering this requires knowing all PHP functions, but I don't know about any. However, you could make your code simpler:

```
function($min, $max, $val) { return min($max, max($min, intval($val))); }
```

Answer (score 1):

No, but can be written in shorter form:

```
function xyz( $v, $min, $max ){
    return min(max( (int)$min, (int)$x), (int)$max);
}
```